# how to count frequency count in triple nested loop

Tags: performance, algorithm, runtime, frequency-analysis

I am trying to determine the frequency count of a triple nested loop.

```
for i = 1 to n do
    for j = 1 to i do
        for k = i to j do
            x =  x + 1
```

I know that  the statement `x = x + 1` will not get executed until i attains the value of n

Any tips/suggestions on how to get started?

Comment: This question would be a better fit on http://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: "x = x + 1 will not get executed until i attains the value of n" is not really true.  It will get executed when i=1 and j=1 and k=1.  And then again when i=1 and j=1 and k=2 and on and on....

Comment: For every `i`, `x=x+1` get executed `r(r+1)/2` times where `r = absolute(1-i)+1`

Comment: Is this the correct code? We have the inequality `j <= i`, so it's odd that the start and stop for `k` are in the other order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take 4 and 5 as examples. When i = 4,

```
...
    for j = 1 to 4 do
        for k = 4 to j do
            x =  x + 1

...j = 1
   for k = 4 to 1 do  // 4 times
       x =  x + 1
...j = 2
   for k = 4 to 2 do  // 3 times
       x =  x + 1
...j = 3
   for k = 4 to 3 do   // twice
       x =  x + 1
...j = 4
   for k = 4 to 4 do   // once
       x =  x + 1
```

When i = 5,

```
...
    for j = 1 to 5 do
        for k = 5 to j do
            x =  x + 1

...j = 1
   for k = 5 to 1 do  // 5 times
       x =  x + 1
...j = 2
   for k = 5 to 2 do  // 4 times
       x =  x + 1
...j = 3
   for k = 5 to 3 do   // 3 times
       x =  x + 1
...j = 4
   for k = 5 to 4 do   // twice
       x =  x + 1
...j = 5
   for k = 5 to 5 do   // once
       x =  x + 1
```

pattern?